# How can I create a custom endpoint with amazon api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

So I have setup up an AWS API Gateway in front of my RESTFUL Flask API hosted on an EC2 instance and served with gunicorn but it gave me a really ugly endpoint to hit, is there a way I could get it on to a custom url?

I've been given this url `https://123x123x.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/myendpoint/`

I'd like to have one like `https://myurl.net/myendpoint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:

1. Assign Cloudfront permission to an IAM user/role in your account:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
         {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontUpdateDistribution",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:updateDistribution"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Define an edge-optimized API endpoint mapped to your current URL
   `https://123x123x.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/myendpoint/`
3. Register a certificate through AWS ACM (or if you have your own CA, create one and import it)
4. Create a custom DNS name in Route 53 for your desired `myurl.net` domain
5. Assign the new custom DNS name to an A Record Alias for the edge-optimized object e.g. `a1b2c3d4e5f6.cloudfront.net`

The longer answer from AWS is detailed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Note: This can also be managed to a great extent with the AWS API Gateway REST API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/domainname-create/

Comment: The API Gateway REST API is just what I wanted, I had no idea thanks!